# android singleTask activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

Looking into activity lifecycle, found following image in android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html):

[image]

How can `Activity Y` be declared as `singleTask`? It is on the top of a task! As I understood it should always be as root activity of a task (be on the bottom of a stack).

Comment: Just because an `Activity` is declared as `singleTask` doesn't mean it has to be the root.

Comment: I think it's a confusing diagram, too. I believe they are trying to illustrate this aspect of singleTask, labeled under the figure: "If the activity is already a part of a background task with its own back stack, then the entire back stack also comes forward, on top of the current task." I don't have time at the moment to throw one together, but a quick test app would probably clear this up better than a diagram or the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You define that in the AndroidManifest.xml where you define your activity. set the launchMode to singleTask:

```
       <activity
        android:name="package.YourActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Comment: How you define singleTask is not the question.

Answer (score 0):

When we define your activity like the code snippet below.

```
    <activity
    android:name="package.YourActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

It will not create a new Task but stack up in the current Task. But when you define like this

```
    <activity
    android:name="package.YourActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity="com.some.somename"/>
```

It will create a new Task (com.some.somename) with the activity as root.